# malloc: *** error for object 0x7fc73ec01800: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, c++14

I have an issue with a method which gives an malloc error when running a test case. The method below is a move assignment. This program is similar to the vector class allowing you to pop and push elements from the head and tail. The assignment below is for copying an array. This is for a coursework.

```
// move assignment
BiArray& BiArray::operator=(BiArray&& other) {
    if (this != &other){
        capacity_ = other.capacity_;   //sets capacity to the other capacity
        mainArray_ = other.mainArray_;  //sets main_array to the other main_array
        size_ = other.size_;             //sets size to the other size
        nextHeadPos_ = other.nextHeadPos_;  // sets the head position to the other head position
        nextTailPos_ = other.nextTailPos_;  // sets the tail position to the other tail position
    }
    return *this;
}
```

And the test case for this method is:

```
void BiArrayTester::testCopyAsg() {
    funcname_ = "BiArrayTester::testCopyAsg";

    int arr[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    BiArray a{arr,10};
    BiArray b;
    b = a;
    if (b.getSize() != 10 || a.getSize() != 10) errorOut_("Unequal size_ reported",0);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        if (b[i]!=a[i] || b[i]!=i || a[i]!=i)
            errorOut_("Unequal value detected",1);

    passOut_("Tested the copy assignment operator.");
}
```

The error that is outputted when the test is ran is:

```
BiArrayTester::testMoveAsg (pass): Tested the move assignment operator.
BiArrayTesterMain(18417,0x118946dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb0e9401740: pointer being freed was not allocated
BiArrayTesterMain(18417,0x118946dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Thanks for any help in advance :)

UPDATE: THIS IS THE MOVE assignment method

New move method is:

```
BiArray& BiArray::operator=(BiArray&& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        int* temp_array = mainArray_;
        mainArray_ = other.mainArray_; //sets main_array to the other main_array
        other.mainArray_ = temp_array;

        capacity_ = other.capacity_;  //sets capacity to the other capacity
        size_ = other.size_;             //sets size to the other size
        nextHeadPos_ = other.nextHeadPos_;  // sets the head position to the other head position
        nextTailPos_ = other.nextTailPos_;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: What happens if `operator=` is called before `mainArray_` has been allocated ?

Comment: I suggest you look up the copy and swap idiom.  It makes the copy assignment operator trivial to implement.

Comment: Sorry, im new to c++ im not sure how to test this @Xatyrian

Comment: @person101 i was pointing out what's probably happening actually, you have to find a way to check if `mainArray_` was allocated before deleting it

Comment: I have allocated mainArray_ in my constructors.

Comment: Works on my machine, after I filled in for the missing code.  The bug is probably in the code not provided.

Comment: @Eljay I updated the question as I think ur right the ouput it get for the error message is pasted above

Comment: Assuming that `mainArray_` was allocated with `new[]`, you did not `delete []` the `this->mainArray_` in the move assignment operator (and then set the pointer to `nullptr`) before the copy.  Thus you are at risk for a double delete error.

Comment: *Sorry, im new to c++ im not sure how to test this @Xatyrian* -- `BiArray b1;...BiArray b2;... b1 = std::move(b2);` --

Comment: The move-assignment method is incorrect, and will result in a double `delete[]` on the same backing store array.  You need to leave `other` in a valid state for destruction, and it does not.

Comment: @Eljay im not sure how to correct this then as I don't have a delete in this method

Comment: @person101 -- *I'm not sure how to correct this then* -- Think logically about this.  You have two objects, one that has data (current object), and the other one where you will be stealing its data from (the passed-in object).  The current object needs to free up the array it has now (delete[] what it has), since it won't be using it again.  After that, it is then going to steal the passed-in object's array from it (the copy is done and then set the passed-in object's data to `nullptr`, i.e. it doesn't have anything anymore).  That is what the move-assignment is supposed to mimic.

Comment: okay thanks I will give it a shot

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have now updated the method to a new one and it passes the test correctly however I am not 100% sure that this is the correct approach.

Comment: *however I am not 100% sure that this is the correct approach.* -- Why not?

Comment: So, my thinking process was that the mainArray is moved to the new one. And then the old one is swapped and gets destroyed in the destructor. Is that correct? @PaulMcKenzie NOTE: My updated method has been added to the post

Comment: @person101 -- You are being confused with the copy/assignment operator.  The move assignment explicitly deletes the old memory, which your update still fails to do.  When doing a move, why wait for the deletion of the old memory to occur at some later time? (it may never occur).  Delete the old memory right there.  Set the passed-in object's data to `nullptr`.  When the `delete` occurs for that object, it is perfectly valid to delete a `nullptr`.

Comment: I tried doing that but as soon as I do that its when it throws the exception in my test case.

Comment: That is probably because you are still using the moved object in some way.   After an object has been moved-from, you shouldn't use it again, except for the reasons I specified above.  The move-assignment operator should look something [like this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71796f745f4c1655)